# Map is capturing Tap events from MapItemsControl elements

Tags: c#, xaml, event-handling, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I have a Bing `Map` control in my Windows Store app. I use the `Tapped` event of the map to place a Pushpin on the selected location.

My map also contains a `MapItemsControl` with some clickable elements. Actually, they're some pushpins that show a popup when clicked.

The problem is that when I click in any of these pushpins, the Map's Tapped event is also fired.

I have also noticed that when this happens all the elements are rendered again, producing a strange behavior on the visual elements.

Any idea why this is happening, and how can I avoid the Map capturing the Tapped event if the Tap has happend on other element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tap event handler for your pushpin tell the event that it has been handled like this:

```
Pin.Tapped += (s,e)=>{
    e.Handled = true;
};
```

This should stop it from bubbling through to the map.

Also, if you want to only let the user add pushpins on the map when they enable the functionality, you can add and remove the tap event as well.